# Appium + Selenium - app activity and app package changes on microsoft azure login page

Tags: android, selenium, appium, android-testing, appium-android

Our app launches the default MS login screen as soon as the app is launched to authenticate the user (Attaching the screenshot of the same).

Now, while using Appium(Selenium with JAVA), the app launches sucessfully, but as soon as the MS login screen is displayed, Appium is not able to identify any element. I tried to print the app activity and app package names on console and turns out that these details are different from one we used while launching the app.

*****APP Details while launching*****:

ACTIVITY:com.abcd.pqrs.ui.mslogin.qwertyLogin

currentPackage:com.abcd.pqrs.qa.debug

****Details once the login page is displayed:***

ACTIVITY:org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity

currentPackage:com.android.chrome

**Any help on how to handle this would be appreciated.***

Answer (score 1):

Native App/Hybrid App + Mobile Chrome Browser Switching

```
String appPackage = "com.android.chrome";
String appActivity = "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"; // OR // org.chromium.chrome.browser.customtabs.CustomTabActivity

//Wait until launch chrome browser OR other browser
Activity activity = new Activity(appPackage,appActivity);
activity.setAppWaitPackage(appPackage);
activity.setAppWaitActivity(appActivity);

switchContextBasedOnString("WEBVIEW_chrome");
new WebDriverWait(androidDriver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("Test1"))).click();

switchContextBasedOnString("Native");
```

I hope this helps.